# C++ thread safety with const functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, const-correctness

So I have a datastructure which ensures thread safety using a rwlock. And I have a RAII ScopedRWLock which locks when created and unlocks when destructor. So for an accessor function, I have:

```
int GetValue() const
{
    ScopedRWLock(&m_rwlock);
    return m_value;
}
```

Now this doesn't work as compiler complains about having the ScopedRWLock with const. I tried replacing ScopedRWLock with just plain read lock and read unlock and doesn't work either. So question is how do people achieve regular (not lock-free) thread safety while still achieving const-correctness??

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to declare your `m_rwlock` as `mutable`, so it is non-const even with const `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create the scoped lock but then immediately destroy it, so it fails to protect your access to `m_value`. You wanted this:

```
int GetValue() const
{
    ScopedRWLock l(&m_rwlock);
    return m_value;
}
```

Now, the lock remains in scope until `m_value` is accessed.

Your probably also want to declare the lock `mutable` so it can be accessed in `const` member functions.

Comment: Damn. You added the answer to your post just when mine was ready. Well done.

Comment: yea that was code on the fly, yea I am creating instance correctly, i'll fix the post above... though about mutable, is that the only way?

Comment: @user1181950 It's not the only way. Another way is to create a lock holder object whose constructor takes a const reference and use that lock holder object.